# On a PUT fetch the CORS issue is triggered "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header", headers setted WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, cors, fetch, php-8

Even though I set the headers in the file functions.php, the error keeps appearing, I tried with several different hooks:

```
function add_cors_http_header()
{
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    // Decide if the origin in $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] is one
    // you want to allow, and if so:
    // header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
  }

  // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
      // may also be using PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
  }
}
add_action('init', 'add_cors_http_header');
add_action('send_headers', 'add_cors_http_header');
add_action('rest_pre_serve_request', 'add_cors_http_header');
```

(Not all add_action at the same time)

And I also tried without the isset and in the header.php

EDIT ---
As requested, the client that is running is Vanilla Javascript, I made the same fetch on Postman and it worked, it's about joining a user to a guild in discord, hre is the code:

```
const args = JSON.stringify({
  access_token: token,
});
const response = await fetch(
  `https://discord.com/api/guilds/${this.guildID}/members/${userID}`,
  {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `BOT ${this.bot_token}`,
    },
    body: args,
  }
);
```

Comment: So in this model, WordPress is the server, but you haven't specified what the client is. For example, is the client JavaScript running in a browser submitting a PUT request on the same domain?

If so, most likely, it's a http/https mismatch. Example:
https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/

Comment: Thanks for the comment Dean, I updated the post with more details, it's running on localhost for now, and besides changing the .htaccess and .config of apache like the post says it didn't work, when I put hte headers as "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" shouldn't it allow any origin? The error says that there is no header, I think the error would be different if it had an error but the origin was different, what do you think?

Comment: When you use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, the value of `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` (if any) is ignored by browsers. Instead of using the wildcard, try specifying the exact origin of your frontend in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. For more about this exception, see [MDN's page about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS): _when responding to a credentialed requests request, the server **must** specify an origin in the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, instead of specifying the "`*`" wildcard_.

Comment: I appreciate the comment jub0bs, I put the domain as specified and I also tried this on my VPS server, and them both kept giving the same error, no matter how I change the headers it says that "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource", so I think that the header is not being sent, which is weird, because as I tested and saw, that line of code is indeed being executed...

Answer (score -1):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin (and similar headers) are for the server to define, and not the client. In this case, the server is the Discord API.

I'm guessing the confusion here is that your client is JavaScript, but you're trying to modify the headers in PHP. I think you should try to add the headers in JavaScript directly. Perhaps there's an `Origin` header you need?

I suggest looking at your Postman headers being sent and add them right in your JavaScript. For example:

```
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Authorization: `BOT ${this.bot_token}`,
  Origin: "http://localhost",
},
```

If that doesn't work, open your Chrome Dev Tools, open the Network tab, and look at the outgoing request, and see what headers it is sending and compare them with Postman. If Postman can work, just repeat what it is doing.

Regarding the WordPress function, I think you can remove it entirely as JavaScript is the client, not PHP/WordPress.